# Getting 4 different images in c# from thispersondoesnotexist.com?

Tags: c#, image, media

I was trying to pull 4 different images from thispersondoesnotexist.com, but it ends up getting duplicate images occassionally. Setting a delay seems to have lowered a chance of this happening, but to eliminate the problem the program would become very slow due to the delays. Can someone come up with a better solution? This is my current code: (the parameters are so it wont get cashed)

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Visible = false;
            var random = new Random();
            var randomnumber = random.Next(10, 30);
            pbPerson1.Load("https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image?a=37645734567");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            pbPerson2.Load("https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image?a=67834562543");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            pbPerson3.Load("https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image?a=33622434768");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            pbPerson4.Load("https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image?a=34688707547");
        }
```

Comment: Your problem does not seem to be code-related (or am I missing something?)

Comment: seems like you should contact the creator of that site.

Comment: You mean you're getting duplicate images when using your `randomnumber ` as URL parameter? Your code is not currently using it. BTW it's being calculated only once.

Answer (score 0):

The site works by randomly generating images on a timer... it takes time to generate the images, it is not intended to retrieve a unique image for every request.

At any rate, this is not related to your code, and is a question that your should direct to the developer of the site (their contact details are on the main page: https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/)